# International student with US visa applying for Canadian eTA

Tags: canada, eta

I am an international student studying in the US.  I am a citizen of one of the countries that do not require a visa from Canada to travel to Canada.  I need to attend a conference in Canada on June 9th and it was dumb of me not to apply for the Canadian eTA earlier than I did (i just knew i didn't have to apply for a visa).  I just applied for an eTA about an hour ago and have only received a confirmation email that they received my application (around 9:40pm EST).

Does this mean they will ask for additional documents in 72 hrs? Or will i most likely hear back with approval tomorrow morning? I read that unless it gets approved within 5 minutes of submission of my application, it will take a long time.

I also read that it may be worth just restarting a process, as in starting a new request on the website from scratch. Is it worth a try?

Comment: We don’t answer opinion based questions here. Relax, you will receive a decision soon.